# How to add an onload without a fetch call in a function based component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

consider the following component in react:

```
import React from "react";
import { Carousel } from "react-bootstrap";
function CarouselHome() {
  return (
    <>
      <Carousel fade pause="hover" id="carousel" variant="">
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img
            className="d-block w-100"
            src="https://source.unsplash.com/1280x400/?bali"
            alt="First slide"
          />
          <Carousel.Caption>
            <p>Bali, Indonesia</p>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img
            className="d-block w-100"
            src="https://source.unsplash.com/1280x400/?maldives"
            alt="Second slide"
          />

          <Carousel.Caption>
            <p>Maldives</p>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img
            className="d-block w-100"
            src="https://source.unsplash.com/1280x400/?greece"
            alt="Third slide"
          />

          <Carousel.Caption>
            <p>Greece</p>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
      </Carousel>
    </>
  );
}

export default CarouselHome;
```

The source.unsplash.com returns an image, but it takes a second or so, thus the rest of the page loads before this component, I want to add a spinner while loading, how do I do this considering this is not even a fetch call?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply logic something like this

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { Carousel } from "react-bootstrap";
function CarouselHome() {
  const [imageLoaded, setImageLoaded]=React.useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <Carousel fade pause="hover" id="carousel" variant="">
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img
            className={`w-100 ${
               imageLoaded ? 'd-block' :  'd-none'
            }`}
            src="https://source.unsplash.com/1280x400/?bali"
            alt="First slide"
            onLoad={()=> setImageLoaded(true)}}
          />
           {!imageLoaded && (
             <div className="smooth-preloader">
                   
             </div>
          )}
          <Carousel.Caption>
            <p>Bali, Indonesia</p>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
      </Carousel>
    </>
  );
}

export default CarouselHome;
```

i declared state variable with the name imageLoaded and changing this state on onLoad function of img and also changing the className based on state change

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with this structure. Create `<Image/>` and `<Loader/>` component.

```
const Image = ({item}) => {
const [imageLoaded, setImageLoaded] = useState(false);

  const handleImageLoad = () => {
    setImageLoaded(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {!imageLoaded && <Loader />}
      <img src={item.src} alt={item.alt} onLoad={handleImageLoad} />
    </div>
  );

}
```